# Overwrite Magento pop-up close onclick event

Tags: javascript, magento, prototype

I have created a custom module in which I used magento pop-up. I want to overwrite pop-up close event.

```
<div onclick="Windows.close(&quot;browser_window_updatecc&quot;, event)" id="browser_window_updatecc_close" class="magento_close"> </div>
```

This is close div id I want to replace that onclick and implement my custom code on onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this to execute when page is loaded:

```
document.getElementById("browser_window_updatecc_close")
        .attribute("onclick","newFunctionName()");
```

Comment: it's a dynamically added id so when i am using getElementbyId its showing me document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: is there any way to access dynamic ids

Comment: are you doing it after the document has loaded?

Comment: Check out this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload